# Stuck in Boolean Algebra equation

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have this equation in Boolean Algebra:

$x*y*z+x'*y*z+x*y'*z+x*y*z' = y*z+x*z+x*y$

I got this:

$= yz(x+x')+xy'z+xyz'$

$= yz+xy'z+xyz'$

And from here I tried multiple things but it goes wrong like:

$yz+x(y'z+yz')$

$yz + x$

Since y'*y and z'*z =0 they disappear so this seemed to be the only answer for me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: But y'z+yz' is not 1 so last step not right.

Comment: That must be where I'm going wrong then.. I'm trying to go on from yz+x(y'z+yz') now

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You could add in a couple of $xyz$ terms into the left side of the original equation.

Comment: So I can use the first xyz term without complements a couple times?

Comment: Yes because $xyz=xyz+xyz$

Comment: yes it's evaluating to the result! So it's good to say here that we might get different expressions while simplifying, but the expression on the left and right would evaluate to same value when we substitute x,y and z in the equation.

Comment: Alright I will try to answer my own question using this then

Answer (score 0):

So using the hint of @paw88789 I got this:

$xyz+x'yz+xy'z+xyz'$

$=yz(x+x')+xz(y+y')+xy(z+z')$

$=yz + xz + xy$

Is this right?

If it is, can I have a little more explanation on why I can use xyz a couple times and if I can do this with all the other terms too?